# How to write an js object into a json-file

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, npm

Now I would like to write this:

myJSONtable

in a JSON file, I have the following approach:

```
    fs.writeFile('./users.json', JSON.stringify(myJSONtable, null, 4), 'utf-8', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('Done!')
    })
```

I have to say that I'm not sure if "fs.writeFile" is the right approach for this.

My Json File should looks like:

```
{
    "Startordner": [
        "C:/GIT/Aktuell/zipper/startordner/"
    ],
    "Speicherorte": [
        "C:/GIT/Aktuell/zipper/zielordner/"
    ],
    "Ignore": [
        "STM32F030RC",
        "Dateinamensliste"
    ],
    "Satz": [
        {
            "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder1",
            "NeuerName": "placeholder1",
            "Revision": "05"
        },
        {
            "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder2",
            "NeuerName": "placeholder2",
            "Revision": "04"
        },
        {
            "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder3",
            "NeuerName": "placeholder3",
            "Revision": "02"
        },
        {
            "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder4",
            "NeuerName": "placeholder4",
            "Revision": "02"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I only get this here:

```
[]
```

myJSONtable looks like this:

```
[Startordner: Array(1), Zielordner: Array(1), Ignore: Array(1), Satz: Array(12)]
Ignore: Array(1)
0: {Ignore: Array(2)}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
Satz: Array(12)
0: {Ursprungsdateien: "placeholder1"}
1: {NeuerName: "placeholder1"}
2: {Revision: "05"}
3: {Ursprungsdateien: "placeholder2"}
4: {NeuerName: "placeholder2"}
5: {Revision: "04"}
6: {Ursprungsdateien: "placeholder3"}
7: {NeuerName: "placeholder3"}
8: {Revision: "02"}
9: {Ursprungsdateien: "placeholder4"}
10: {NeuerName: "placeholder4"}
11: {Revision: "02"}
length: 12
__proto__: Array(0)
Startordner: [{…}]
Zielordner: Array(1)
0: {Zielordner: Array(1)}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**I can still be helped, thanks in advance.**

Comment: You need to serialize your object. What is the type of `myJSONtable`?

Comment: That's an array -> var myJSONtable = [];

Answer (score 0):

Most probably myJSONtable variable is array with item that is a class with **getters**. They are not visible in the JSON.stringify() output.

You can write your own serialize method in that class where you will manually return object where each field's value is manually called or use some dedicated library like **class-transformer**:

```js
import { classToPlain, Expose } from "class-transformer";

class Satz {
  constructor(ursprungsdateien, neuerName, revision) {
    this.ursprungsdateien = ursprungsdateien;
    this.neuerName = neuerName;
    this.revision = revision;
  }
}

const item1 = new Satz("placeholder1", "placeholder1", "05");
const item2 = new Satz("placeholder2", "placeholder2", "06");

class SomeClass {
  @Expose()
  get startordner() {
    return "C:/GIT/Aktuell/zipper/startordner/";
  }

  @Expose()
  get speicherorte() {
    return "C:/GIT/Aktuell/zipper/zielordner/";
  }

  @Expose()
  get ignore() {
    return ["STM32F030RC", "Dateinamensliste"];
  }

  @Expose()
  get satz() {
    return [item1, item2];
  }
}

const someClass = [new SomeClass()];

// this returns only [{}]
console.log(JSON.stringify(someClass, null, 4));

const someClassPlain = classToPlain(someClass);

// this returns all getters
console.log(JSON.stringify(someClassPlain, null, 4));
```

By default library ignores getters but you can force them to be visible after serialization by using Expose decorator. If you cannot use decorators in your project the fallback is always to write your own serialize method.

Here is the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-66238400?file=index.js

Comment: That looks very good, but my problem is that I have to use the object, I can't write something hard, because I don't know which data will come.

Comment: It should only have the structure from the json file shown, I react variably to the content

Comment: Ok. So let's maybe clarify from where you get myJSONtable variable. Because clearly something is wrong with that variable that it prevents it from being serialized. There is no such thing as private member of the object in JavaScript. Can you console.log myJSONtable[0].Satz or any other part of that structure?

Comment: Also please try to console.log serialized variable or part of it without saving to the file. If it will output proper string then it's the file issue, if not it's the variable issue. Also you could try to use fs.writeFileSync(). Maybe there is some async data issue there - in general it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a solution elsewhere and found it. My problem is simply that I fill an array, the solution is, quite trivial, **I just have to fill an object**, for this I simply changed the declaration dof myJSONtable to.

```
var myJSONtable = {};
```

Nevertheless thanks for the help.
Sorry for the bother, I hope someone else can work with my question and the following answer.